# Nonin Oximeter 3231

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to read in data from the Nonin Pulse Oximeter model 3231 using the USB connection. The data is coming out in this from (b'\x14\x00\x02B\x02\xc2b\x00N\x03\x02\n') when I am reading it in using the pyserial documentation. I am not sure how to turn this into the SpO2 and heart rate data that I am looking for.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

import serial
import binascii
s = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbmodem5055968061",9600, bytesize=serial.NINEBITS)

try:
while True:
data = s.readline()

```
    print(s.is_open)
   # decode_hex = data.decode("ascii")
    #decoded_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(data)
    #decoded_string = decoded_bytes.decode('ascii')
    # Process the received data
    print("Received:", data)
    #print("Hex:",decode_hex)
    #print("Edit:", decoded_bytes) # So we are receiving, but not receiving data.
```

except KeyboardInterrupt:
# Close the serial port when interrupted
s.close()